# XYChart.Series not serializing in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a javafx health program with an object Person with a XYChart.Series parameter. After I create the user when I call my save() method, I'm getting the error `Error writing to data file: javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series`

This is my code when I create the person and add it to my ArrayList userlist:

```
Person person  = new Person(height, weight, age, waist, gender, username, password, activityIntensity, calorieSeries, waterSeries, exerciseSeries);

userList.add(person);
```

And my method to save:

```
public void save()
{
    FileOutputStream fileID;
    ObjectOutputStream outFile;

    try
    {
        fileID = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
        outFile   = new ObjectOutputStream(fileID);

        outFile.writeObject(userList);

        outFile.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error writing to data file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Before, I was saving arrayLists rather then XYChart.Series and that worked fine, but I don't understand why it's not saving XYChart.Series to the .ser file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XYChart.Series` class is not `Serializable`, so you will get an error when you try to serialize any object that contains that as part of its persistent state. You have a couple of options:

1. Don't persist the chart data. You can do this by including the chart data field as `transient`
2. Implement [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) instead of `Serializable`. You will have to implement the `readExternal` and `writeExternal` methods. This might be a bit of a pain, as you seem to have a lot of fields, but basically your `writeExternal` method would write all the serializable fields, then write a serializable form of the chart data (e.g. write the data in an `ArrayList`). The `readExternal` method would read the data back in (in the same order) and reconstitute the field values from it; for the chart data it would read the `ArrayList` (for example) and construct the chart data from it.

You didn't post your `Person` class, so I can't really give more detail on how to do it, but that description should be enough.

Just a comment: it seems like a slightly odd design to have your `Person` class (which is inherently model data, i.e. an entity) keep a reference to an `XYChart.Series` (which is really UI data, at best it belongs in a View-Model). The entity should really be agnostic as to how the data in it is presented. It may be better to revert to using a `java.util.List` in the `Person` class, and "wiring" the data from there to your chart elsewhere.